# Using VB to get 1st of July in previous year

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am trying to create a default date in SSRS using VB. 
The date I am trying to create is the 1st of July in the previous year from the current year.

I am using something like this at the moment to get the current day in the previous year at 6am.

=CDate(Format(DateAdd("yyyy",-1,Now()), "yyyy-MM-dd") + " 06:00:00")

Comment: Take a look at the overloaded method `=New Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression to get 6pm of the 1st of July of the previous year is:

```
=  Cdate(Cstr(Year(Today())-1) & "-07-01 06:00:00")
```

To get 6pm for the same date of the previous year

```
=  Cdate(Cstr(Dateadd(DateInterval.year,-1,Today)) & " 06:00:00")
```